# Vue js and laravel keep an uploaded image permanently

Tags: laravel, image, vue.js, file-upload

I wrote a code to upload an image file and that is already working, I also can save the image url in my database. The problem is the image is not loaded permanently. Which means I can see the image after I uploaded it, but the moment I save it, the url is not valid anymore. Does anyone know how to fix it? I mean store the image permanetly on my project. I want users to upload and use their own images? Thank you for youre help.

uploading in template
`<input style="margin-left: 35px" type="file" @change="onFileChange" />`

Displaying the image
 `<img v-if="data.image" :src="data.image" style="max-width:450px;vertical-align:middle;margin:0px 5px 5px"/>`

script method

````
      onFileChange()e {
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      this.data.image = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    },```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in your Controller:

```
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:2048',
    ]);

    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();  //What you store in DB

    $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName); //Put the image in a public folder
```

And from there you could access it via URL.